# R Survey library Difference of Means Test

Tags: r, statistics, survey

I am currently using R's `survey` library to analyze survey data. I have two samples from two different time periods. My goal is to test if the difference between the two *weighted* sample means is equal to 0. **Question: How do I approach this using R's survey library?**

I have tried two approaches to doing this:

### Approach 1: Create two different postStratify objects. Toy example:

```
q1 = c(1,1,1,1,0)

group = c(0,0,0,1,1)

df = data.frame(q1, group, time)

svy_design = svydesign(ids = ~1 , data = df)

pop_data = data.frame(group = c(0,1), Freq = c(10,90))

ps_design = postStratify(svy_design, strata = ~group,pop_data)

first = svymean(q1, ps_design) #Weighted Mean of first sample


q1 = c(1,1,1,0,0)

g2 = c(1,1,0,0,0)

df2 = data.frame(q1, g2)

pop_data_2 = data.frame(group = c(0,1), Freq = c(20,80))

svd_2 = svydesign(ids = ~1, data = df2)

psd_2 = postStratify(svd_2, strata = ~g2, pop_data_2)

second = svymean(q2, psd_2) #Weighted mean of second sample
```

---

The problem with this approach is that I do not know how to conduct the difference of means test on "first" and "Second" - the two `svymean` objects.

### Approach 2: Create only one postStratify object. Toy example:

```
q1 = c(1,1,1,1,0, 1,1,0,0,1)

group = c(0,0,0,1,1, 0,0,1,1,1)

time = c(0,0,0,0,0, 1,1,1,1,1) #Variable that distinguishes between the samples

df = data.frame(q1, group, time)

svy_design = svydesign(ids = ~1 , data = df)

pop_data = data.frame(group = c(0,1), Freq = c(10,90))

ps_design = postStratify(svy_design, strata = ~group,pop_data)

svyby(~q1, ~time, ps_design, svymean)

svyttest(q1~time, ps_design)
```

---

The problem with this approach is that when i run `svyby` just to check the created mean values, the output of `svyby` is not what I expect. It puts out `mean = 0.5714` for `time = 0`, when the theoretical weighted mean for that is 0.55. **Any insight as to why the theoretical mean differs from that of `svyby` will be greatly appreciated.**

Thank you so much for your time.

Answer (score 0):

are you looking for this?  thanks

```
library(survey)

q1 = c(1,1,1,1,0, 1,1,0,0,1)

# edited #
group = c(0,0,0,1,1, 2,2,3,3,3)

time = c(0,0,0,0,0, 1,1,1,1,1) #Variable that distinguishes between the samples

df = data.frame(q1, group, time)

svy_design = svydesign(ids = ~1 , data = df)

# edited #
pop_data = data.frame(group = c(0,1,2,3), Freq = c(10,90,20,80))

ps_design = postStratify(svy_design, strata = ~group,pop_data)

svyby(~q1, ~time, ps_design, svymean)

svyttest(q1~time, ps_design)
```